# ng-click not work in div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

i've been stuck here for a while, when i'm using "form" tag everything is ok but in "div" tag ...

**main.js:**

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('appctrl', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.start = function (name) {
        console.log(name);}
 }
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" ng-controller="appctrl">
            <input id="input" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autofocus="true" placeholder="Please enter your full name" type="text" ng-model="name">
            <div id="button" ng-click="show()">Start Demo</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the method `show` isn't defined anywhere

Comment: @SterlingArcher thanks, I was working for hours and I think I'm a bit tired and I have to rest ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app.controller('appctrl', function ($scope) { 
    $scope.name = null;   
    $scope.show = function (name) {
        console.log(name);
    }
});
<div id="container" ng-controller="appctrl">
            <input id="input" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autofocus="true" placeholder="Please enter your full name" type="text" ng-model="name">
            <div id="button" ng-click="show(name)">Start Demo</div>
        </div>
```

You're calling `show()` but you defined `start()`

Comment: Why couldn't i see it?

Comment: May be you need to pay more attention to detail @Mr.Python

Answer (score 3):

I think you need this, you need to name the function as **`show`** , also you need to pass parameter to the function show.

additionaly you are missing **`)`** in your controller.

```
app.controller('appctrl', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.show = function (name) {
        console.log(name);}
 }
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('appctrl', function ($scope) {    
    $scope.start = function (name) {
        console.log(name);
        }
        
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" ng-controller="appctrl">
            <input id="input" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off" autofocus="true" placeholder="Please enter your full name" type="text" ng-model="name">
            <div id="button" ng-click="start('TEST')">Start Demo</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```